# angular how to pass in http dependency?

Tags: angularjs, webdriver, protractor

trying to call an angular service from my ngapp in my jasmine script:

```
  it('should create client', function () {
        browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback) {
            var api = angular.injector(['$http','myservices']).get('custService');
            api.saveClient({name:'Ted'},function(data){
                console.log(data);
                callback(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

My question is how can I pass in the http dependency because now I am getting this error:

```
  UnknownError: javascript error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $http due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module '$http' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

Comment: I tried that , now I am getting:     UnknownError: javascript error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $angularCacheFactoryProvider . How can I pass this in?

Comment: tryin to create a new customer before I start testing. I am in running protractor and trying to call a service that is defined in my angular website

Comment: [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

Answer (score 0):

You should use mock data instead of creating a real object.

Doing a real http request is not a good idea.
Use mocking in the responses as @merlin said in the comments. Try to use $httpBackend to mock your response.

A quote from the documentation :

> $http service sends the request to a real server using $httpBackend service

You can inject your mock there like in the example :

```
beforeEach(
  inject(function($injector) {
 // Set up the mock http service responses
 $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
 // backend definition common for all tests
 authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', '/auth.py')
                        .respond({userId: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});
  // ...
}
```

If you need the http service anyway, you should inject it like the following

```
var myHttpService;
beforeEach( inject(function($http) {
   myHttpService = $http;
}));
```

After that you can expect a http GET for example to happen. You should call the $httpBackend.flush because in a test scenario it won't run async and $http uses promises in the background. See examples in the documentation.